# Client Login for Google Drive API

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api, gdata, google-docs-api

I am having problems getting a Client Login to work with the ruby Google Drive client API. How do you go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that. ClientLogin is deprecated and doesn't work with new APIs like Drive. Use OAuth 2.0:

https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth

Comment: The problem is that I was hoping to have all the Google Docs belong to one central account for the app. Is this possible now that ClientLogin is deprecated?

Comment: Yes, use a service account.

Comment: I took a look at the documentation for service accounts, but it seems that ruby is not supported. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Service accounts with Ruby:https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/ServiceAccounts